# How to detect whether the current line is empty line?

Tags: vimscript

I want a command mapping to detect whether the current line is blank, and perform a different action for each case it detects: true of false. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not entirely clear when you say to "trigger some mapping"... Do you want to create a mapping with `nnoremap` if current line is empty? I guess not. Or you want to have a mapping that does different things depending on whether current line is empty?

If so then there are many possibilities, for example:

```
func! DoSmth()
    if getline('.') =~ '^\s*$'
        echo 'Do something if empty line!'
    else
        echo 'Do something if NOT empty line!'
    endif
endfunc

nnoremap <space>a :call DoSmth()<CR>
```

Comment: Yes I meant the second one you mentioned.

Comment: May I also ask you that how to detect the previous line exists?

Comment: @job_start it would be better to create another question for this. But in general, check `:h function-list` in vim to get an idea of what API vim exposes to vimscript.